# Is there a way to send reminder emails for a collector using the Survey Monkey API C#?

Tags: surveymonkey

I didn't find any documention about automation remainder emails using surveymonkey api. Can anyone please let me know how to send remainder emails using Api in c#.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the SurveyMonkey API docs [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3). To create a reminder message you can just do:

```
POST /collectors/<collector_id>/messages
{
    "type": "reminder",
    "recipient_status": "has_not_responded",
    "subject": "Reminder! We want your opinion"
}
```

And that'll create a new message for all recipients that haven't responded (there are other options, as well you can modify the body of the email, see the [docs](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages)).

You can then [schedule the message](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-send) to be sent like this:

```
POST /collectors/<collector_id>/messages/<message_id>/send
{
    "scheduled_date": "<iso_date>"
}
```

And that'll send a message at the specified date (you can leave out the scheduled date to send right away).

With regards to specifically with C#, there's an SDK I've seen used a few times on github you can find [here](https://github.com/bcemmett/SurveyMonkeyApi-v3/). It doesn't seem to have a create message function, but can be easily added in, it's basically [this method](https://github.com/bcemmett/SurveyMonkeyApi-v3/blob/master/SurveyMonkey/SurveyMonkeyApi.Collectors.cs#L61) except don't use `Page` and the URL parameters but instead do a `POST` request with a json body and convert it to a `Message` object.

Hopefully that can get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem @Yadav , if I answered the question well enough do you mind marking it as accepted? Thanks.